# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed" in django-rest-framework (for permission_classes = IsAuthenticated and more where it allowed GET method)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, permissions, get

Help please!
I have installed for view class permission_class which allow GET-requests, but when i send GET-request i get messege: GET method is not allowed

i have **views.py** file:

```
class WomenAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Women.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WomenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )

class WomenAPIUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Women.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WomenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
#    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )

class WomenAPIDestroy(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Women.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WomenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )
```

In **views.py** file i use basic integrated **IsAuthenticated** class for **WomenAPIUpdate**:

```
class WomenAPIUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Women.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WomenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
#    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
```

My **urls.py** file looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/drf-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v1/women/', WomenAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/women/<int:pk>/', WomenAPIUpdate.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/womendelete/<int:pk>/', WomenAPIDestroy.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    re_path(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('api/v1/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/v1/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/v1/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
]
```

And for **WomenAPIUpdate** class i have installed next url:

```
path('api/v1/women/<int:pk>/', WomenAPIUpdate.as_view()),
```

But when i make GET-request to this url i get messege: **"GET method is not allowed"** (i get same messege during using Postaman and Browser).

Here is my **models.py** file:

```
class Women(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    car_id = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Пользователь', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried create own permission classes where i allowed GET method during using integrated tuple **SAFE_METHODS** and installed them to **WomenAPIUpdate class**, but it did'nt work:

```
class IsAdminOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
     def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.user == request.user
```

**SAFE_METHOD** tuple:

```
SAFE_METHODS = ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS')
```

It worrked until i created Authentication settings and instelled them in **settings.py** file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply Both cases like this ....

#### With Browser (Session and Basic Both worked with Browser but at time you can apply only one) (Handle Session)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        # -------------- OR -------------------------
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

#### With Postmen (Handle JWT Token)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the view `WomenAPIUpdate` use are inheriting `generics.UpdateAPIView` which will only allow `PUT or PATCH` methods, which means it will only allow you to `UPDATE` an object, not to FETCH/GET data.

If you are trying to use GET method in postman, it will throw error.

For getting one object, either inherit from `generics.RetrieveAPIView` or

change this

`class WomenAPIUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):`

to

`class WomenAPIUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):`